# Android UI и размеры экранов и различные разрешения

Tags: android

Если ориентироваться на то, что например xhdpi - 720-1280, xxhdpi - 1280-1920, hdpi - 480-800, mdpi - 320-480... То как быть с размерами самих экранов? К примеру подготовив изображения для xhdpi - они отображаются "как нужно" на 4.7 дюймовых экранах. Но xhdpi у нас не ограничивается только 4.7 экранами, и есть размеры больше, соответственно эти же картинки на больших экранах, будут отображаться маленькими. Как быть в таком случае? Вообще не могу уловить эту "закономерность". Мне как казалось, что должны быть какие либо встроенные инструменты вроде редактора иконок, который сам подстраивает размеры под разные типы экранов.... а тут получается не пойми что.

Answer (score 1):

видимо вы путаете плотность пикселей и размер экрана

плотность пикселей это количество пикселей помещающиеся в квадрат со сторонами 1 дюйм (модификатор указывается у папок drawable)

а есть модификатор для размера экрана (указывается для папок layout и values)

то есть вам надо учитывать эти два параметра, все картинки(drawable) автоматически увеличиваются\уменьшаются при необходимости (обычно отключено), но картинку 100x100 пикселей (px) не растянешь на 10000x10000 px  (картинка испортится) и на оборот тоже самое, потому вам надо делать несколько вариантов одной и той же картинки под разную плотность экрана, вы их и кладёте в папки с модификаторами а андроид потом сам разбирается какую папку использовать

Answer (score 0):

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) утилита для иконок тоже имеется ─ [тут ее веб версия](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) но это только для иконок самого приложения наиболее подробно описано в манах